# Kendo-ui template syntax produces uppercase text

Tags: kendo-ui

When using the Kendo UI template syntax to insert a JavaScript literal value, it produces uppercase text. For example, the following:

```
#= "Time" #
```

Converts the "Time" into "TIME" when it renders the HTML.

Why is this and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce such behavior with the following code:

```
kendo.template('#= "time test" #')({})
```

Anyway you do not need to put these strings inside of the #= # expression - usually you want to evaluate variables.

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ixenik/2/edit) for your code.

Comment: yes, the literal value was just to illustrate the issue in its simplist form. The issue was that the body tag had a CSS stylet hat transformed all text to uppercase